# how to install crypto-sha1 in meteorjs

Tags: meteor, meteorite

when am installing the  crypto-sha1 in meteorjs, getting this issue.

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
Problem installing crypto-base
✘ [3.1.2.1] conflicts with [3.1.2.0]
Can't resolve dependencies! Use --force if you don't mind mrt taking a wild guess and running your app anyway.
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have multiple packages depending on `crypto-base`, one which is asking for `3.1.2.1` and one asking for `3.1.2.0`. Either change one of the packages so that they are asking for the same version or take one of them out.

You can check if `mrt update .` will grab the latest versions of both and solve this automatically.